# Lorentz force not experienced when current is parallel to magnetic field; why?

Tags: electromagnetism

Lorentz force is not experienced when the current flows parallel to the magnetic field. Now, can someone explain me the reason to this? I can't understand this.

Comment: Physics *describes* nature.   For the reason why, you'll have to ask the creator of nature.  I don't think he or she subscribes to this forum.

Comment: This question is answered in this post - http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29133/37364.

Answer (score 1):

A current is simply moving (with velocity $v$) electrons (with charge $q$), so we apply the following equation for the lorentz force: 
$$\vec{F}=q \vec{E}+q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}.$$

In the absence of an electric field, we thus have 
$$\vec{F}=q \vec{v} \times \vec{B}.$$

For two parallel vectors, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{B}$, the cross product vanishes, so $F=0$.